# jquery ready function executing twice when I click on an anchor tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My code is below:
when I click on anchor tag, this below explained function is executing twice. What should I add in it?? Or am I missing some thing???

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("a").bind('click', function (ev) {
        if ($(this).attr('title') == "delete_data") {
            _operation($(this).attr('title'), $(this).attr('id'));
        } else {
            // url to open page  
            if ($(this).attr('title') == "view_data") {
                if (childWindow) childWindow.close();
                childWindow = window.open( /*option to open window*/ );
            } else {
                if (childWindow) childWindow.close();
                childWindow = window.open( /*option to open window*/ );
            }
        }
        return false;
    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: What if you put `alert('foobar');` instead of `bind`? Would you see 2 alerts?

Comment: The only possibility that I see which could explain this behavior is in the HTML: Do you accidentally have an anchor nested an other anchor ?

Comment: Could you reproduce the issue on a [fiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: It may you have load the document twice. By ajax or something else??

Comment: return false both the times? or should last one be return true?

Comment: check jquery script called twice in a page...

Comment: Not the problem, but no need to return `false` (or any other value) from your document ready handler. (You _do_ - probably - want to return `false` from your click handler.)

Comment: I cheked my code once again. I don't have an anchor tag nested in another anchor tag.

Comment: @zerkms: I used alert('foobar'); instead of bind. It is coming twice.

Comment: @nnnnnn returning false from the handler would workaround the issue, but hide the real problem, which may indeed be jQuery script included twice

Comment: hi guys! Although now the problem is solved just by placing method="post" in the <form> tag. But can any body explain why the problem is solved just by doing this??

Comment: What form is that? What other information haven't you mentioned yet?

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me you want

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("a").click(function(ev){         
    if($(this).attr('title') == "delete_data"){       
      _operation($(this).attr('title'),$(this).attr('id'));   
    }
    else {
      var url = ($(this).attr('title') == "view_data")?"url1":"url2"; 
      if(childWindow) childWindow.close();
      childWindow = window.open(url);            
   }                     
   return false;
  }); 
});
```